# How to alter pandas key when it's an object

Tags: python, pandas, object

I have a dataframe that is imported from another system, the keys are causing me trouble.

They look like this:

```
'87450912562906\n0972\nT_cust\n[Ah]'
```

when checking dtype returns 'object'.

I want to simplify and remove the \n that is causing me another problem.

I would like to loop over and alter the keys to:

```
'C1_0972_cust_[Ah]'
```

and the number of characters for '0972' in above example can vary between 4 - 6, and be both number and letters.

I have tried:

```
for name in df.keys(): 
     #name = str(name) <-- does not work 
     #name.replace('\n','') <-- does not work
```

I have also tried .rstrip() just to se if I am able to cut characters, but I am not.

Seems I am unable to do anything with this 'object'. (The need for altering the key came from having problems comparing keys from two dataframes, suspected reason is the \n in the keys)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For dataframes, `keys` are `columns`, and you want to replace `columns` as a whole:

```
df.columns = [x.replace('\n', '') for x in df.columns]
```

or equivalently

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace('\n', '')
```